# What is the exact difference between count[name.charAt(i)]++ and count[str1.charAt(i) - 'a']++?

Tags: java

I understood that the below code counts up the number of occurrences of each letter in name string.

```
String name = "haier";
int[] count = new int[256];
for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
     count[name.charAt(i)]++;
}
```

But in couple of places in some tutorials I can see  `- 'a'` added like mentioned below

```
for(int i=0; i<str1.length();i++) {
    count[str1.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
}
```

As per the articles `- 'a'`, is used t0 shifts"the ascii/unicode values. Which I am not clear and didn't understand. Can some one help to understand the exact difference between both `count[name.charAt(i)]++;` and `count[str1.charAt(i) - 'a']++;` and in which use case should I use  `- 'a'`

Comment: `int i = 'a'; System.out.println(i);` - This might help.

Comment: Supposing that `name` and `str1` refer to the same `String`, the difference, obviously, is that the two expressions modify different elements of `count`.  Which, if either, alternative you should use depends entirely on which element of `count` you in fact want to modify.

Comment: If the `charAt(i)` is a `c`, that means the `int` value isn't 1, but is actually the ASCII value of it, so subtracting `a` gives the value 1, which is what you want to add to your counter.

Comment: @notyou did you confuse `c` and `b`? Or `2` and `3`?

Comment: @Turing85 What do you mean?

Comment: @notyou Oh there is a typo in my comment... I meant `1` and `2` instead of `2` and `3`. Why shoulc `c` have the value `1`? If anything, one would expect it to have the value `2` (neglecting the ascii-value, of course).

Comment: In Java (and .NET, JavaScript, …), strings are sequences of char. char is a UTF-16 code unit. (UTF-16 is a character encoding for the Unicode character set.) So, `int[] count = new int[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1];` might work out best. See [MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE). Java does not intrinsically use ASCII—it's just one of the many dozens of really old character sets that you might occasionally need to convert to or from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `count[name.charAt(i)]++;` then the length of `count[]` must be at least 122 because ASCII value of z is 122.

But when you use `count[str1.charAt(i) - 'a']++;` you can reduce the length of array `count[]` to 26 because there are only 26 characters`(a-z)` (If we consider only characters).

In other words `'z' - 'a'` means `122-97 = 25` i.e. max length is `26`

The main purpose of this array seems to count the occurrences of each alphabets.

***For example*** if `str1.charAt(i)` is c then count['c' - 'a']++ means value at count[2] and 2 is the 3rd position in array i.e. count for 3rd character `c` and each time character `c` encounters it increments value at count[2]

Comment: What does ASCII have to do with it, or the char 'z' in particular?  Java `char`s can directly represent non-ASCII characters, with values much larger than 122 (or 255).

Comment: @JohnBollinger `'In other words 'z' - 'a' means 122-97 = 25` means it increments value at `count[25]` by 1. As I said just to save array memory. By character I meant Alphabets

Comment: You are missing my point.  Your explanation assumes that the string `name` will contain no characters greater than 'z' or less than 'a'.  This is not safe or reasonable without external assurances that have not been provided by the OP.  Indeed, his question absolutely hinges on that issue.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes you have a valid point. But as OP is explicitly using alphabet `a` it's kind of predictable

Comment: No, the OP is asking *when he should* use the `- 'a'`, and why.  Part of an answer might then be "not when the string may contain chars less than 'a'."

Comment: that's what I mentioned in the answer i.e. to reduce the array size. If we don't use `-'a'` the we need to take array length of 122 at least because ASCII value of `z` is `122` and `-'a'` means we reduce size by `97` i.e. size 26 is enough

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik [`char`s are 16-bit unicodes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)...